# comparing 2 lists with additional data to be printed

Tags: sed, awk, grep, join

I have a file lets say file1.txt

```
ENSG00000223116 AL157931.1  
ENSG00000233440 HMGA1P6 
ENSG00000207157 RNY3P4  
ENSG00000229483 LINC00362   
ENSG00000252952 RNU6-58P
```

I have another file say file2.txt

```
ENSG00000223117 0   0
ENSG00000223116 0   0
ENSG00000233440 1.71449394  50
```

I want to compare file1 with file2 for ENSG names and get the output such that if ENSG name in file 1 is present in file2 then output should be

```
ENSG00000223116 0   0 AL157931.1
ENSG00000233440 1.71449394  50 HMGA1P6
```

I can write a perl script for this but I just want to do this on command line. How can it be done?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried `join`?

Answer (score 3):

If you previous sort your files, you could do in a simple way:

```
$ join file2 file1
ENSG00000223116 0 0 AL157931.1
ENSG00000233440 1.71449394 50 HMGA1P6
```

To sort your files just do the following:

```
sort file1.txt > file1
sort file2.txt > file2
```

Comment: Or: `join <(sort file2.txt) <(sort file1.txt)`